# What is Arnold Hotel Font™?

Tags: pattern

This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a font shares a specific commonality with another font, it's an Arnold Hotel Font™.

Use the following examples below to find the commonality. **Clarification:** This is asking specifically about the typeface being used, not the name of the typeface/letters contained within.

[image: Font List]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Arnold Hotel Font™, Non-Arnold Hotel Font™
GARAMOND,CALIBRI
ANTONIO,VERDANA
UNIVERS,CAMBRIA
GOTHAM,BODONI
BEMBO,GILL SANS
AVENIR,LUCIDA
CHAMPION,PERPETUA
FORMATA,ROCKWELL
GEORGIA,TAHOMA
VITESSE,ONYX
CALIFORNIAN,PAPYRUS
```

**Note:** There are other Arnold Hotel Fonts™ than the ones on the list.

---

**Hint 1**

> (((((((((7+2)-1)+1)+1)-1)+1)+1)+1)+2)

---

**Hint 2**

> Brownie birth Home

---

**Hint 3**

> The person in charge, alternatively, the place they're in charge of:
>  MPIUTRCDHUDEANIELS
>  MIINCDHIAAENLAMCROBBIE
>  WMAALRLYALCAENLDOH
>  MOIHCIHOASETLAVTDERAKE
>  EPREINCNJSBTAARTREON
>  RROUBTEGRETRLSBARCHI
>  RIOLBLEIRNTOJIJSONES
>  BIROUWCAESHTAARTREELD
>  JMOIANNNGEASBOETLA
>  RNOENBNRIAESDKGAREEN
>  JNLOARNTDHIWSEMSATRETRINN
>  RWEIBSECCOCNASBILNANK
>  SMAIMCUHEILGLASNTSATNALTEEY
>  MMAIRCKHSISGCAHNLISSEL

---

**For @hdsdv (and anyone else following along at home)**

> For your spoiler block #1, take a look at the second piece of documentation(s) you mentioned.
>  For your spoiler block #2: Who are some famous/well-known Arnolds?
>  For your spoiler block #3: refer back to my hint for your spoiler block #1

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether this is actually about the _names_ or the _typefaces themselves_? (Of course the ambiguity may be entirely deliberate and I'm not suggesting there's anything wrong with that.)

Comment: Good comment! Let me clarify.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan and therefore there's no word-prop tag ;)

Comment: There are many typefaces called Garamond, some of which are very different from one another. Several of the things listed here are actually families with many members (including e.g. roman and italic variants which may have very different letterforms). Again, any ambiguity here may be very much intended, but would you like to offer any clarification on how to identify e.g. a particular version of Garamond or a particular weight of Univers if we need to? (Again: absolutely fine not to.)

Comment: rot13(V gubhtug vg zvtug or sbagf gung ner abg vafgnyyrq fgnaqneq ba Zvpebfbsg Jbeq, ohg Trbetvn vf fgnaqneq)

Comment: I'm unsure if being a graphic designer helps me or hinders me.

Comment: rot13(Gurl ner abg frevs if fnaf frevs orpnhfr Tnenzbaq vf frevs juvyr Nagbavb vf fnaf frevs)

Comment: Why the image, if it provides no useful information? Wouldn't it be better to have samples of the relevant fonts instead?

Comment: @Deusovi samples of relevant fonts would provide no more useful information to solving this "What is..." Than a list of names would.

Comment: @Deusovi In addition to the typefaces' names and the letterforms themselves, there are also things like their designers, the foundries that sold them, the dates when they were created, what if anything they were named after, what other typefaces they were inspired by (or shamelessly copied from), etc. The names are more useful than the letterforms for trying to find such things.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (10/11).

That's quite a big hint. It looks like the Arnold Hotel fonts

> are or have been used in the logos or official branding guides of Big Ten universities.
>
>     Nebraska - Garamond, Gotham, Avenir
>
>     Iowa - Antonio
>
>     Michigan - Univers
>
>     Illinois - Univers
>
>     Ohio State - Univers (deprecated, replaced by Proxima Nova and Capita)
>
>     Michigan State - Gotham
>
>     Maryland - Bembo
>
>     Penn State - Avenir
>
>     Purdue - Champion
>
>     Rutgers - Formata
>
>     Indiana - Georgia
>
>     Wisconsin - Vitesse
>
>
>     Still working on these:
>
>
>     Northwestern - Georgia (I had to find their Word document template to see this, and if this is the intended mapping I find it somewhat disappointing - their official fonts are Periódico, Campton, and Akkurat)
>
>     Minnesota - ??? Currently Neutraface, cannot find any references to any of the listed fonts.

Oh also,

> I have no idea how to connect the title. Trying to incorporate the hint, I looked for broadly famous Arnolds (Palmer, Schwarzenegger, and there are very few others). Arnold Palmer went to Wake Forest, an ACC school. Arnold Schwarzenegger graduated from University of Wisconsin - Superior. I suppose this could be the connection but it seems very tenuous, since this association is not well-known or often-discussed. There are some Big Ten athletes named Arnold (Arnie Risen, Kenny Arnold) but again they don't seem broadly famous enough to justify the title. I feel like I'm still missing something here.

As for the missing one,

> Californian is UC Berkeley's logo. Not sure how that fits with all the Big Ten schools.

Comment: You're most of the way there! I'll add a few hints up in my original post that will hopefully help you (or someone else) wrap it up.

Comment: I was able to find rot13(Trbetvn va Abegujrfgrea'f qbjaybnqnoyr Jbeq qbphzrag grzcyngr. Guvf frrzf yvxr n fgergpu, ohg bu jryy. Nf sbe Zvaarfbgn, abar bs gurve qbphzrag grzcyngrf ner ninvynoyr sbe qbjaybnq jvgubhg ybttvat va gb gurve flfgrz. Gur Zvaarfbgn jbeqznex ybbxf xvaq bs yvxr Pnyvsbeavna, ohg vg vfa'g (lbh pna frr zvabe qvssreraprf va gur G naq S, sbe rknzcyr.)